# How to recover [admin] password for neo4j

Tags: neo4j

Some weeks ago, I was testing Neo4j 2.2.4 version installed on my P.C.

I've changed the neo4j/neo4j default password, but after this, I've had a big problem and I lost all my Firefox password box. So I've no save for it!

- Where I can find the passwd file on my disk ?
- Is it necessary to re-install all ?

Answer (score 2):

To reset the password you can simply delete `data/dbms`. The next time you access the Neo4j Browser you will be prompted to set a new password.

Comment: That seems to be the better way. +1

Comment: Good, 've rename auth-save, and it ask me a new pass

Answer (score 1):

You can stop the neo4j server, and disable the required web authentication in the config file **neo4j-server.properties** by setting:

`dbms.security.auth_enabled=false`

Then restart the neo4j server and you can use it again.

*Alternatively*
you could also install the newer version (always a good thing), move your graph.db into the new installation of neo4j and start the server there. It'll ask you about setting your authentication credentials there.

Comment: Good, it does not ask login